# gulp filters javascript files and not css files

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I am a newbie to gulp. I am trying to create one single vendor.css file and vendor.js file with gulp.

The vendor.css should be

```
 -bootstrap.css
```

The vendor.js should be

```
 -jquery.js
 -bootstrap.js
 -angular.js
 -angular-ui-router.js
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
// Include Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');
// Include plugins
var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
    pattern: ['gulp-*', 'gulp.*'],
    replaceString: /\bgulp[\-.]/
});
// Define default destination folder
var dest = 'public';

gulp.task('vendorjs', function(){
    var filterJS = plugins.filter('**/*.js');
    return gulp.src('./bower.json')
        .pipe(plugins.mainBowerFiles( ))
        .pipe(filterJS)
        .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())
        .pipe(filterJS.restore())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest+"/vendor/js/"));
});
gulp.task('vendorcss', function(){
    var filterCSS = plugins.filter('**/*.css');
    return gulp.src('./bower.json')
        .pipe(plugins.mainBowerFiles( ))
        .pipe(filterCSS)
        .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.css'))
        .pipe(plugins.uglify())
        .pipe(filterCSS.restore())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest+"/vendor/css/"));
});


gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});

gulp.task('serve', ['vendorcss','vendorjs'], function () {

});
```

When i run gulp serve, it executes without error. But I end up with

```
public/vendor/css/angular/angular.js 

public/vendor/css/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js

public/vendor/css/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js

public/vendor/css/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less

public/vendor/css/jquery/dist/jquery.js

public/vendor/js/vendor.js

public/vendor/js/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
```

1. Why do my css files are missing. Why do i get less file.

My output should be

```
public/vendor/vendor.js
public/vendor/vendor.css
```

2. How do i map the vendor.js and vendor.css with my html